# How long will a Google Apps Script continue to run unattended

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a standalone Script, which is stored in my Drive account and I have set up a trigger to run it at set intervals (several times daily, if it's relevant).

If I don't log in to my account and the Script doesn't experience any unhandled errors or exceed quotas, how long will it continue running unattended?
Indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've set up a trigger as you've described, the script will continue run indefinitely, *even if there are* errors or exceeded quotas. (It will launch - but may fail again or get killed immediately for exceeded quota.)

For this reason, you should ensure that you have set notifications appropriately.

In [Understanding Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers), the behaviour of time-based triggers is explained, but it does not explicitly state that triggers run indefinitely. On the other hand, it does not say that they stop running - implying that they don't. (I have triggers that have been running daily for years.)

There have been reported instances of triggers misfiring (Issue [2708](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2708), [2746](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2746), [2547](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2547)), as well as a personal favourite - scripts that continue to trigger after deletion (Issue [143](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=143)).

Comment: Thanks - do you have a source for where you found this info?

Comment: Mostly personal experience and stuff I've gleaned from others here on SO, but I've added some more info to the answer, linking to known issues.

Comment: It would be good for the google apps script team to include this kind of detail to the [Dashboard](https://script.google.com/dashboard).